# Serie en Java: -1,2,2,-3,4,4,4

Tags: java

tengo esta serie como tarea:
-1 , 2 , 2, -3 , 4 , 4 , 4, - 5 , 6, 6, 6, 6, -7
llevo rato intentando encontrar la solución pero no he logrado nada. 
Espero que me digan en qué estoy mal
Mi codigo hasta el momento:

```
 public class Java1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
         /*Construya un programa en JAVA y RUBY. Que calcule e
        imprima la siguiente serie para los N primeros
        términos
        -1 , 2 , 2, -3 , 4 , 4 , 4, - 5 , 6, 6, 6, 6, -7 …*/

       int n, i;
       Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
       n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el valor de N: "));

       for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
            if(i%2==0){//si es par
            for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
             System.out.print(""+i+",");
                }
            }
            else{//si es impar
            i= i*-1;
            System.out.print(""+i+",");
            }


       }


    }
}
```

Comment: La lógica parece estar bien, pero estás usando el mismo índice i en ambos bucles, por lo que los valores se deben sobreescribir. Utiliza otro nombre de variable para el bucle interior y te funcionará.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Este seria tu codigo corregido:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Digite el valor de N: "));
        int oddCount = 1;

        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            if((i + 1) % 2 == 0){//si es par
                for(int j = 0; j < oddCount; j++){
                    System.out.print("" + (i + 1) + ", ");
                }
            }else{//si es impar
                System.out.print("" + ((i + 1) * -1) + ", ");
                oddCount++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Lo primero que hay que tener en cuenta y no olvidar nunca es que los arreglos siempre empiezan desde el indice `0`, y tu estabas empezando desde el indice `1` en tus ciclos:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
   ...
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
      System.out.print(""+i+",");
   }
   ...
}
```

Lo segundo es que estabas usando tu variable `i` en tu segundo ciclo, lo cual es incorrecto, debido a que recuerda que `i` va cambiando en el tiempo, por lo tanto el segundo ciclo estaba tomando como indice el indice del primer ciclo (que tambien es `i`).

Otra cosa a tener en cuenta, es que a menos de que estes usando un ciclo `while`, tus indices no deberían estar definidos afuera:

```
int n, i;
```

Para el caso de `n` esta bien, pero para el caso de `i` deberia definirse dentro del ciclo:

```
for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
   ...
}
```

Corrigiendo un poco estos errores hay varios cambios que hice al codigo, por ejemplo, en tu código utilizabas un solo indice para los dos bucles (`i`):

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
   ...
   for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
      System.out.print(""+i+",");
   }
   ...
}
```

En el código que modifique uso dos indices, `i` y `j`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    ...
        for(int j = 0; j < oddCount; j++){
           System.out.print("" + (i + 1) + ", ");
        }
    ...
}
```

De esta manera no estaríamos usando el indice del otro ciclo, el cual definitivamente interferiría en alguno de los dos ciclos.

Tambien agregue fuera del ciclo esta variable y la inicie en `1`:

```
int oddCount = 1;
```

La cual permite llevar una cuenta de cuantas vecez has llegado a la parte donde te encuentras con numeros impares negativos.

Esta variable seria usada posteriormente en el ciclo `for` para imprimir tu sencuencia de numeros positivos pares de manera correcta y con la cantidad correcta.

Otra diferencia entre tu codigo y el mio es que tu tienes:

```
if(i%2==0){
   ...
}
```

Y yo tengo:

```
if((i + 1) % 2 == 0){
   ...
}
```

Lo cual realmente es lo mismo, solo que tu empezaste tu ciclo desde el indice `1` mientras que yo lo empece desde el indice `0`, por esta razon la condicional cambia, al tener que sumarle uno.

Ahora bien tu en el segundo for tenias:

```
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
    System.out.print(""+i+",");
}
```

Lo cual es exactamente lo mismo que tenias en tu `for` principal, no es esta la condicion en la que deberia correr el segundo ciclo, puesto que la idea no es recorrer e imprimir los numeros desde `i + 1` hasta `n`, si no mas bien imprimir el numero `i` x vecez, donde `x` seria la cantidad de vecez que nos hemos topado con un numero impar negativo.

Asi que para solucionar esto hacemos uso de nuestro contador de numeros impares negativos en el segundo ciclo `for`:

```
for(int j = 0; j < oddCount; j++){
    System.out.print("" + (i + 1) + ", ");
}
```

Por ultimo en el `else` tu tenias:

```
else{//si es impar
    i= i*-1;
    System.out.print(""+i+",");
}
```

Lo cual lo que hacia era cambiar a `i` a un numero negativo o positivo (depende de si `i` era positivo o negativo) y luego imprimias `i`, pero ojo!, **no debes cambiar el valor de i directamente**, puesto que esto afecta tambien a las iteraciones del ciclo, por poco y casi creas un bucle infinito.

Por esta razon en vez de reasignar a i:

```
i= i*-1;
```

Lo que se hace es directamente mostrar `i` multiplicado por `-1`, esto no reasigna a `i`, por lo cual la variable no es afectada:

```
else{
    System.out.print("" + ((i + 1) * -1) + ", ");
    oddCount++;
}
```

Y ademas a `oddCount` le sumamos una unidad, para poder que cada vez que entremos al segundo ciclo `for` la cantidad de vecez que imprimamos el numero vaya acorde con la cantidad de vecez en las que nos hemos topado con un numero negativo impar.

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda! Logré hacerlo de esta manera: for(i=1;i<=n;i++){
            if(i%2==0){//si es par
            for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
            System.out.print(i+",");
                }
                        }
             else{//si es impar
             num= i*-1;
             System.out.print(num+",");
            }


       }

Comment: @RicardoMorelos de nada amigo!, recuerda que si te fue de ayuda mi respuesta puedes darle click al boton que parece un chulo, para dar la respuesta como aceptada, quiza le pueda servir a otros usuarios.